# Facebook popup auth error

Tags: c#, facebook, internet-explorer

I have the following code

```
FB.init({
    appId: '999999999999',
    status: true, 
    cookie: true, 
    xfbml: true, 
    channelURL: 'http://mydomain.com/channel.aspx',
    oauth: true 
});

FB.login(function (response) { 
  ...
}
```

All works great in Chrome, FF, Opera on Macs and PC's, however in IE9 on a PC I get the following error on the popup

[image: Error msg]

And in the developer tools I get a error here: SCRIPT70: Permission denied. Can anyone shed any light into this?

[image: Error in IE Developer tools]

Comment: Since it's IE, it may be blocking your script for some security reason. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will have to answer my own question here in case it affects anyone else.

After extensive searching and playing with P3P headers nothing worked. However I started looking at other FB apps and they all suffered the same problem on IE9. This led me to believe that it could actually be my machine.

I tested my app on two other VMWares running ie9 and on my laptop and everything worked as expected. Therefore there is something wrong with my setup, pass what it is....

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a problem when you start debugging. Just close IE, open again the web page and see if the permission denied error happens again. 
If you start debugging the error will be thrown again.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is related to your problem, but I had some very specific security issues working with FB authentication (only on IE) which were solved by adding a P3P header to the HTTP response. More details can be found [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=452) or [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/).

Comment: I have seen this problem but to no avail, looking for alternatives.